# How to create a spark data frame from a txt file with multiple data points, each having a label and 4 features and their values given like 1:0.4

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, google-colaboratory

So, I have a txt file with a rows of numbers

```
0.0 1:5.1 2:3.5 3:1.4 4:0.2
0.0 1:4.9 2:3.0 3:1.4 4:0.2
...
```

and so on.

`0.0` is a label, `0.0`, `0.1`, `0.2` and so on.
the column separated values are features and the respective feature's values.

I want to load this to spark dataframe.

I did the following but the features are returned as nulls.

```py
# Define the schema
schema = StructType([
        StructField("label", FloatType(), nullable=False),
        StructField("feature1", FloatType(), nullable=False),
        StructField("feature2", FloatType(), nullable=False),
        StructField("feature3", FloatType(), nullable=False),
        StructField("feature4", FloatType(), nullable=False)
])

# Load the data into a DataFrame using the specified schema
df = spark.read.option("delimiter", " ").csv("file_path", schema=schema)

# Show the first few rows of the DataFrame
df.show()
```

Comment: All data are typed as FloatType but in your exemple i see that you have the following values: 3:1.4 4:0.2 that does not respects the type provided(caused by the :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`1:5.1` is definitely not a float so spark does not understand the records you provide. You have to read the CSV as string and then do the work yourself as follows:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = spark.read.option("sep", " ").csv("filepath")

df.select(
    [df['_c0'].alias("label")] +
    [F.split(df[f'_c{i}'], ':').getItem(1).cast("float").alias(f"feature{i}") for i in range(1, 5)]
).show()
```

```
+-----+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|label|feature1|feature2|feature3|feature4|
+-----+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|  0.0|     5.1|     3.5|     1.4|     0.2|
|  0.0|     4.9|     3.0|     1.4|     0.2|
+-----+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```